# python lists: print values which have an even index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to define the indexes of values stored in a list acquired by an input. Then I need to return the values which have an even index.
So far I have part of my code, but I think there is something missing. Also my program keeps on running and doesn't break.
I cannot see why, I tried to program a break into it but it keeps giving me errors.

If the input would be "5 4 3 2 1"
the output should be "5 3 1"

````
getal = ""
reeks = []

reeks = input("Geef een reeks getallen in : ")    

getallen_reeks = [int(getal) for getal in reeks.split(" ")]

for getal in getallen_reeks:

    getallen_reeks.append(getal)
    if getallen_reeks.index(getal)%2 == 0:
        print(getal) ```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you are appending things again back to the the parent list

so the list keeps on growing:

**remove:**

```
getallen_reeks.append(getal)
```

This will stop it from running the loop for ever:

The correct approach would be :

```
getal = ""
reeks = []
reeks = input("Geef een reeks getallen in : ")
getallen_reeks = [int(getal) for getal in reeks.split(" ")]
[print(getallen_reeks[n]) for n in range(0,len(getallen_reeks),2)]
```

you can use range or enumerate to make it less expence operation:

Output:

[image]

Comment: It would still be highly inefficient and a potential source of bugs to use `.index`…

Comment: @deceze agree added that to answer

Comment: 1) You could simplify that approach using `range(0, len(getallen_reeks), 2)`. 2) Don't use list comprehensions as a substitute for `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate(list)`. Like,

```
getal = ""
reeks = []

reeks = input("Geef een reeks getallen in : ")

getallen_reeks = [int(getal) for getal in reeks.split(" ")]

for idx, getal in enumerate(getallen_reeks):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        print(getal)
```

Tested with your input

```
Geef een reeks getallen in : 5 4 3 2 1
5
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not loop.  Use list slicing:

```
>>> l = '5 4 3 2 1'
>>> l[::2]
'54321'
```

Oops, i forgot to split the values!

```
>>> l = l.split(" ")
>>> l
['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
>>> l[::2]
['5', '3', '1']
>>>
```

l[::2] takes every 2nd element in the list, starting with the first (zeroth) element